# Prevent Hyper-V host from sleeping if guest VMs are running

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019, hibernate

I have a Windows Server 2019 workstation running Hyper-V, with a Ubuntu 20.04 VM. I can `ssh` into the VM remotely, so I rarely log into the host OS.

As a consequence (and unless I disable sleeping entirely), Windows will put the workstation to sleep after a while, *regardless* of the state of the guest VM. Ideally, instead, the workstation should go to sleep only if

1. The host OS has been inactive for *x* minutes, *and*
2. None of the guest VMs are running.

However, I cannot find anything relevant to this issue in Windows' control panel, nor in Hyper-V's settings.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Comment: Don't use a workstation to do a server's job. If you must use a workstation then configure it as you would a server and disable sleep altogether.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by combining a couple of built-in tools in Windows. You need:

1. Two power plans

   - One that prevents sleep
   - Another that allows sleep
2. A PowerShell script
3. A Scheduled task

This solution is tested and is currently in use on my Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise build 22621. Works perfectly for me but your mileage may vary.

## The Solution

### Power plans

Create two power plans in your host computer. Name them **Always on** and **Balanced**. Configure them respectively. The second one might already be present. These names are hard-coded in the following script so, if you pick other names, you have to edit the script accordingly in the next step.

### Powershell script

Next, paste this PowerShell code into a file named **Hyper-V-PowerPlan.ps1** in your **Windows** directory. If you want to pick some other directory or file name, then you have adjust the path accordingly in the final step.

```
# Hyper-V-PowerPlan.ps1
Import-Module Hyper-V
# 'Off', 'Saved', 'OffCritical', 'SavedCritical'
$offstates = [Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMState[]](3, 6, 32786, 32788)
if ($(@(Get-VM).ForEach({$_.State -in $offstates})) -contains $false) {
    $desired = 'Always on'
} else {
    $desired = 'Balanced'
}
$plans = Get-CimInstance -Namespace ROOT\cimv2\power -ClassName Win32_PowerPlan |
    Group-Object -Property ElementName -AsHashTable -AsString
if ($plans.ContainsKey($desired) -and -not $plans[$desired][0].IsActive) {
    $plans[$desired] | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Activate
}
```

### Scheduled task

Finally, create a new scheduled task using *Create Task...* menu option (don't choose basic version) and enter the following settings:

**General** tab

- When running the task, use the following user account: **SYSTEM**
- Run with highest privileges: **[checked]**

**Triggers** tab

- Create new trigger
- Beging the task: **On an event**
- Log: **Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker/Admin**
- Source: **Hypver-V-Worker**
- Event ID: (leave empty)
- Enabled: **[checked]**

**Actions** tab

- Create new action
- Action: Start a program
- Program/script: **%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe**
- Add arguments (optional): **-NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%SYSTEMROOT%\Hyper-V-PowerPlan.ps1"**

**Settings** tab

- These two are optional:

  - Stop the task if it runs longer than: **1 minute** (you have to type "minute" manually)
  - If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop: **[checked]**
- If the task is already running, then the following rule applies: **Queue a new instance**

Save the scheduled task and you are done! Whenever you have VM running, your host computer's power plan gets automatically switched to one that prevents it from sleeping, and back to balanced when the last VM gets turned off.

## How this all works

When you start, stop, or do some other actions on a VM on Hyper-V, an event is written into **Microsoft-Windows-Hyper-V-Worker/Admin** event log. Every time this happens, the scheduled task you created gets notified about the event and it triggers the scheduled task action. The action runs the PowerShell script you created.

Script works by enumerating all VMs found on the host computer. If any of the VMs is in the state *other than* "Off", "Saved", "OffCritical", "SavedCritical", then the host computer's desired power plan name is set to "Always on". Otherwise it's set to "Balanced". After the desired power plan name is determined, all power plans found on the host computer are enumerated. If the currently active power plan name is different than the desired name, and a power plan with the desired name is found, the `Activate` CIM instance method of the desired power plan object is invoked. It's equivalent to you switching the power plan manually.

Answer (score -2):

`Invoke-CimMethod` will result in error on Win10 21H2.

```
Invoke-CimMethod : This method is not implemented in any class 
At C:\Scripts\Hyper-V-PowerPlan.ps1:13 char:24
+     $plans[$desired] | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Activate
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (Win32_PowerPlan...d-445e-4ebe...):CimInstance) [Invoke-CimMethod], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041055,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand
```

Source: xPowerPlan: Trying to use it on Windows 10 fails with no Activate method error [LINK](https://github.com/dsccommunity/ComputerManagementDsc/issues/155)

Comment: It is always best to format your answer correctly to make it legible. Also, please [edit] your answer and provide a reference source where it states that `Invoke-CimMethod` should be replaced with `Powercfg`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).